# Video ripping software into HEVC (x265) for Windows 10

Tags: video, ripping

### Goal

I would like to rip my own, very long, home made, movies into [HEVC (x265)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X265).
They are currently saved in x264 using HandBrake, RF 15 or something similar to preserve quality. They are 1080p in size.

### Question

This question is all about various approaches as to how to accomplish this task.
That is:

- Name any software you have yourself used and have experience with! (For us to be able to place questions on you, if necessary.)

### Hardware

CPU: [Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ @ 2.80 - 3.80 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/products/97185/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz), Kaby Lake:

> The Kaby Lake & Coffee Lake microarchitecture adds full fixed-function H.265/HEVC Main10/10-bit encoding and decoding acceleration & full fixed-function VP9 8-bit & 10-bit decoding acceleration & 8-bit encoding acceleration

RAM: 16 GB DDR4 2400MHz

GPU:

- Integrated: Intel® HD Graphics 630, [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) capable
- Dedicated: [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce%20GTX%201060%20with%20Max-Q%20Design&id=3769) with [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/10series/laptops/max-q/) 6GB GDDR5, Pascal architecture, [NVIDIA NVENC x265 capable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC)

### Requirements for answers

- Please adhere to my hardware configuration.
- State what acceleration method(s) the software is capable of.
- State its license model.
- You may include what special features your recommended software has.
- You may include how intuitive the user interface is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/)

- License: Open-source, GPLv2, [details on GitHub](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/blob/master/LICENSE).
- Acceleration: Pure **CPU** or [**Intel Quick Sync Video**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video), **no support** for [**NVIDIA NVENC x265**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC).
- User interface: Extremely intuitive.
- Features: I don't know about *special* features, but it has presets for one, and plenty of available settings.

Answer (score 0):

## [StaxRip](https://github.com/stax76/staxrip/), [documentation](http://staxrip.readthedocs.io/)

- License: Open-source, MIT, [details on GitHub](https://github.com/stax76/staxrip/blob/master/License.txt).
- Acceleration: [**NVIDIA NVENC x265**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC) supported, pure **CPU** or [**Intel Quick Sync Video**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video), **AMD** too.
- User interface: Very unintuitive. You may have to dig yourself into different settings options.
- Features: It may very well have the most of features I have ever seen, yet again, in unintuitive UI.